# Image not initially rendered on mobile

Tags: angular

I am using this image cropper
https://embed.plnkr.co/VFwGvAO6MhV06IDTLk5W/

it's working fine on desktop. But when loading an image on mobile the image is not rendered until touching the screen. In Angluar2 is there way to force rendering after the image is loaded?